# Blazor App - Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor App that runs perfectly well on localhost, however, when I deploy it to the server I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Forbidden
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Forbidden
Error: Error: Forbidden
Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

error comes from  blazor.server.js.

I looked everywhere and there is no such error reported as far as I know.

Comment: What server and how is it configured?  Could be WebSockets is off. But there should be a fallback.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that was pretty much it. The websocket was being blocked by the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, firewall was blocking it. Simply changing it's security to a lower level did the trick